# is there any way to see 3 way to sumbit error?

Tags: unix

Hello how can I know the type of error I am killing in Linux
I need three ways, meanwhile I have two one is through a code program in C, and the other is through the terminal with the command and it returns the error type to me the problem is I need a third way I would be happy to help

Comment: to review error in kill() command

Comment: What's a _sumbit error_?

Comment: i need to know error like EPERM

Answer (score 0):

The third way is look at syslog

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```